# Custom panels page not showing page title

Tags: 7, panels, chaos-tool-suite

I have some custom panels pages I have created and have added the Page Title pane to page content.

[image: Picture showing panel page setup with page title field filled]

However, the Page Title pane is only rendering when the page is in a menu and we're on the url in the menu.   If the page is being viewed but the url is not on a menu then the page title doesn't show.

I would have expected the page title to show regards if it was part of a menu or not.

Comment: I've been having the same issue.  Looks like this may be recent... possibly with the last update.